# Concatenation of same first letter (case insensitive) in C program

Tags: c, arrays, string

We have to write a program that would combine first letter alike in alphabetical order.
E.G. input= Tea,boat,bee,toe,Baby. The output should be =Babybeeboat,Teatoe. But my program would print the same string twice before combining the words. Here's my code:

```
//how to combine first letter alike string

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char str1[1000][1000], str[1000], temp[1000];
    int n, i, p, j, a;
    char *ptr, *ptr1;

    printf("Enter how many arrays: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter string %d: ", i+1);
        scanf("%s", &str1[i]);
    }

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<n-i-1; j++)
        {
           if(strcmp(str1[j], str1[j+1])>0)
           {
               strcpy(temp, str1[j]);
               strcpy(str1[j], str1[j+1]);
               strcpy(str1[j+1], temp);
           }
       }
    }

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<i-1; j++)
        {
            a=strncmp(str1[j],str1[j+1],1);
            if(a==0)
                printf("%s", str1[j]);
            else
                printf(",");
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<i-1; j++)
        {
            a=strncmp(str1[j],str1[j+1],1);
            if(a==0)
                printf("%s", str1[i]);
            else
                printf(",");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is plenty more you can do before asking someone else to debug your code for you. Suggest you step through your code with a debugger and/or add more debug print statements. If you are still stuck after that then come back to share with us what you have found so far in your debugging.

Comment: You can simply use an `std::vector` of type `std::string` and use `sort (vector.begin (), vector.end (), /* COMPARISON FUNC */);`

Comment: @Raymond - this appears to be strictly C code and was incorrectly tagged as C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going wrong in the last few for loops:

> ```
> for(i=0; i<n; i++)
> {
>     for(j=0; j<n-i-1; j++)
>     {
> ```

The outer loop should stop at n-1 and the inner loop should start from i+1 (i.e. next string in array) to n:

```
for(i=0; i<n-1; i++)
{
    for(j=i+1; j<n; j++)
    {
       if(strcmp(str1[i], str1[j])>0)
       {
           strcpy(temp, str1[i]);
           strcpy(str1[i], str1[j]);
           strcpy(str1[j], temp);
       }
   }
}
```

Then you just need one loop after this that checks the first character of the strings in the array. If the character is different you print `,<string>`. Store the character for comparison in the next iteration.

```
char letter;
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    if (i != 0)
    {
        if (str1[i][0] != letter)
        {
            printf(",");
        }
    }

    printf("%s", str1[i]);
    letter = str1[i][0];
}
```